# Python - Remove items with same name but different extension from a list

Tags: python, list, image, data-cleaning

I have a list of pictures when for every picture in *.jpg* format I have one corresponding *.mov* file with the same name. I want to remove all *.mov* files that have a corresponding *.jpg* file only, for there are other *.mov* files that I want to maintain, as they do not represent pictures but videos and so they are not paired with any *.jpg* file.

So far, I have written a code that does almost everything I want to. Here it is:

```
pics = ['IMG_0000.MOV', 'IMG_2812.JPG', 'IMG_2812.MOV', 'IMG_2815.JPG', 'IMG_2815.MOV', 'IMG_2853.AAE', 'IMG_2862.MOV', 'IMG_2944.JPG', 'IMG_2944.MOV', 'IMG_2955.JPG', 'IMG_2958.JPG', 'IMG_2958.MOV', 'IMG_2965.JPG', 'IMG_2965.MOV']
print('Original list:', pics)
print('------')
# Get rid of all the files different from .mov and .jpg
lista = []
for i in pics:
    if i.endswith('.JPG') or i.endswith('.MOV'):
        lista.append(i)
#print(lista)

# Remove all .mov files that are immediately preceded by a .jpg file
nuevo = [a for a, b in zip(lista, [''] + lista) if b.endswith(".MOV")]
print('Output list:', nuevo)
```

where I get this output:
[image]

There are two problems:

1. This code always removes the first item in the list. The very first item should never be removed as there will never be a .jpg file immediately preceding it. How can I prevent the code from erasing the first element in the list?
2. Sometimes there are several *.jpg* files next to each other, in which case I would like to maintain all of them, for I just want to get rid of *.mov* files with a corresponding *.jpg*.

Can you help me improve my code so that it works as expected?

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing your data is already sorted. In that case, I'd use `itertools.groupby` to group the files and filter-out the `.MOV` where the length of group is greater than 1:

```py
from itertools import groupby

lst = [
    "IMG_0000.MOV",
    "IMG_2812.JPG",
    "IMG_2812.MOV",
    "IMG_2815.JPG",
    "IMG_2815.MOV",
    "IMG_2853.AAE",
    "IMG_2862.MOV",
    "IMG_2944.JPG",
    "IMG_2944.MOV",
    "IMG_2955.JPG",
    "IMG_2958.JPG",
    "IMG_2958.MOV",
    "IMG_2965.JPG",
    "IMG_2965.MOV",
]

out = []
for name, group in groupby(lst, lambda k: k.rsplit(".", 1)[0]):
    group = list(group)
    out.extend(f for f in group if not (f.endswith(".MOV") and len(group) > 1))

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[
    "IMG_0000.MOV",
    "IMG_2812.JPG",
    "IMG_2815.JPG",
    "IMG_2853.AAE",
    "IMG_2862.MOV",
    "IMG_2944.JPG",
    "IMG_2955.JPG",
    "IMG_2958.JPG",
    "IMG_2965.JPG",
]
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I want to remove all .mov files that have a corresponding .jpg file only ...
>
>
>
> Can you help me improve my code so that it works as expected?"*

You can use a *list-comprehension*.

```py
b = [x for x in pics if not x[x.rfind('.') + 1:] == 'MOV'
                     or x[:x.rfind('.')] + '.JPG' not in pics]
```

Alternately, a basic *for-loop*.

```py
b = []
for s in pics:
     i = s.rfind('.')
     if not s[i + 1:] == 'MOV' or s[:i] + '.JPG' not in pics:
          b.append(s)
```

Output

```
IMG_0000.MOV
IMG_2812.JPG
IMG_2815.JPG
IMG_2853.AAE
IMG_2862.MOV
IMG_2944.JPG
IMG_2955.JPG
IMG_2958.JPG
IMG_2965.JPG
```

Answer (score 0):

collections.deque with yield is good to use here.

```
from collections import deque

pics = ['IMG_0000.MOV', 'IMG_2812.JPG', 'IMG_2812.MOV', 'IMG_2815.JPG', 'IMG_2815.MOV', 'IMG_2853.AAE', 
       'IMG_2862.MOV', 'IMG_2944.JPG', 'IMG_2944.MOV', 'IMG_2955.JPG', 'IMG_2958.JPG', 'IMG_2958.MOV', 
       'IMG_2965.JPG', 'IMG_2965.MOV']

def search_list(pics_list):
    previous_lines = deque(maxlen=1)
    for item in pics_list:
        yield item, previous_lines
        previous_lines.append(item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pics_list = pics[:]
    print(pics)
    for item, pre_item in search_list(pics):
        if len(pre_item) == 0:
            pass
        else:
            pre_item_name = pre_item[0]
            if item.endswith('.MOV') and item.split('.')[0] == pre_item_name.split('.')[0]:
                pics_list.remove(item)
    print(pics_list)
```

['IMG_0000.MOV', 'IMG_2812.JPG', 'IMG_2812.MOV', 'IMG_2815.JPG', 'IMG_2815.MOV', 'IMG_2853.AAE', 'IMG_2862.MOV', 'IMG_2944.JPG', 'IMG_2944.MOV', 'IMG_2955.JPG', 'IMG_2958.JPG', 'IMG_2958.MOV', 'IMG_2965.JPG', 'IMG_2965.MOV']

New List:

['IMG_0000.MOV', 'IMG_2812.JPG', 'IMG_2815.JPG', 'IMG_2853.AAE', 'IMG_2862.MOV', 'IMG_2944.JPG', 'IMG_2955.JPG', 'IMG_2958.JPG', 'IMG_2965.JPG']